# How to the get test data (provided by dataprovider) in the method "onTestStart" of iTestListener

Tags: java, testng

So the problem I am trying to solve is :

I have test class and a `@test` method `runtest` which receives data from a data provider. I want to perform some action based on the test data run test is going to receive from the data provider, before starting the runtest method.

For this I was looking at `iTestListener`, it has a method `onTestStart` but I am not able to figure out how to get the test data for that instance of run in the method.

Any other good approach is welcome.

Comment: How do you start your test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class extending TestListenerAdapter

```
 public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult tr) {
       super.onTestStart(tr);
       Object[] params = tr.getParameters();
       String a = (String)params[0];
       int b = (int)params[1];
       //Add whatever you want to do before the test case starts
    }
 }
```

Add annotation to your test class

```
@Listeners(ResultReporter.class)
public class CoreSingleApplicant1TestCase {

   @Test(dataprovider = "dataprovider",dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class))
   public void runtest(String a, int b){
   }
}
```

Dataprovider class

```
public class StaticProvider {
  @DataProvider(name = "create")
  public static Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { 
         {"String", 1},
         {"Integer",2} }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you will get the test data which will be supplied to the test method. My data provider is in a different class. Not in the test class.

//Add whatever you want to do before the test case starts
How do you get the test data passed  here ?  Thats what i need to know.

Comment: Updated the the answer after your requirements